# CSS3 Transition - expand visible part of image

Tags: html, css, background, css-transitions

I want to use CSS3 to make a transition but I'm new to the subject and can't really see how I'm supposed to get started on my idea. I did some research, but I had a very specific thougt in mind and there's not that much examples of that available.

I want to make a transition that only shows the first card at the beginning, but when hovered on, the image box spreads slowly so the other cards appear.

[image: This is the image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? It would be a great help and a nice lesson for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `<div class="cards">` element with background of your image:

```css
div.cards {
  width: 43px;
  /* width of one card */
  height: 65px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivCAY.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
/* then on hover: */

div.cards:hover {
  width: 550px;
  /* width of full image */
}
```

```html
<div class=cards />
```

Comment: is there a possibility to do this gradually, like in a transition?

Comment: For `transition` property, only `-webkit-` vendor prefix is needed. [source](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition)

Comment: [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YjjB/1/) based on @YotamOmer code. I just added a `last-child`

Comment: Make sure to set the correct image path.. I set `url(cards.jpg)` as an assumption..

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it doesn't load for some weird reason. It doens't even keep space open while width is defined

Comment: Weird.. sure you set `class="cards"` on the `<div>` element? the code seems right..

Comment: Yeah, I thought it seemed right too, I really don't know what's going on with it... I even made an empty page linked to the style sheet so nothing can interfere with it and it still gives me a big blanc.

Comment: Maybe you have other `div.cards` in your stylesheet? or something that overrides.. try it with a blank page and only the relevant css.

Comment: I've found the problem, if the div is empty the div won't show for some reason, when I put text in, it does. Only, the card is vertically split in half, and the height element doesn't do a thing.